# How to iterate products in a shopify template

Tags: iteration, shopify, shopify-template, shopify-api

i'm new to Shopify. I need to create a custom theme for a shop and i'm practicing with loops. But i have a problem with a basic products iteration. [in developers guide i saw this](https://shopify.dev/docs/themes/liquid/reference/tags/iteration-tags#for)

I used :

```
 {% for product in collection.products %}
    {{ product.title }}
 {% endfor %}
```

i added this code in index.liquid template, but it doesn't iterate anything.
Someone can help me?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because **collection** is a Liquid object that is available only on Collection pages. You can read more at [Liquid Objects](https://shopify.dev/docs/themes/liquid/reference/objects).

To iterate on index.liquid, you need to use some [Global Shopify Object](https://shopify.dev/docs/themes/liquid/reference/objects#global-objects). For example, using the collections object, you can iterate like

```
{% for product in collections.frontpage.products %}
  {{ product.title }}
{% endfor %}
```

**Frontpage** in above code is the name of collection. Replace it with your collection that is on your store and has some products.